# cmake/vcpkg on Linux: unable to detect the active compiler's information

Tags: linux, cmake, vcpkg

I am able to get cmake/vcpkg to function correctly for my C project on windows, but on Linux it doesnt seem to work. I've installed vcpkg by following the instruction from its official website, but running the vcpkg install gives me this error:

```
Fetching registry information from https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg (HEAD)...
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-linux...
error: while detecting compiler information:
The log file content at "/root/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/stdout-x64-linux.log" is:
-- Configuring x64-linux-rel
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:112 (message):
    Command failed: /root/vcpkg/downloads/tools/cmake-3.27.1-linux/cmake-3.27.1-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake /root/vcpkg/scripts/detect_compiler -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/root/vcpkg/packages/detect_compiler_x64-linux -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/root/vcpkg/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-linux/ninja -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/root/vcpkg/scripts/toolchains/linux.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux -DVCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG=ON -DVCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=external -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP=TRUE -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DVCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS=OFF -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/root/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -DCMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION=ON -DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS= -DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG= -DVCPKG_C_FLAGS= -DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG= -DVCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE=dynamic -DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS= -DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG= -DVCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin -D_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=/root/vcpkg -DZ_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=/root/vcpkg -D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=/root/CLox/vcpkg_installed -DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF
    Working Directory: /root/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      /root/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/config-x64-linux-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
      /root/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/config-x64-linux-rel-out.log
      /root/vcpkg/buildtrees/detect_compiler/config-x64-linux-rel-err.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:344 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  scripts/detect_compiler/portfile.cmake:18 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)



error: vcpkg was unable to detect the active compiler's information. See above for the CMake failure output.
```

I am using cmake for the project, though I suspect it is a vcpkg issue, or perhaps theres something I need to edit in cmakelists.txt? This error appears even if I just run command `vcpkg install` without building it with cmake.

I also notice that vcpkg is trying to use cmake 3.27.1 on linux, while when I run `cmake --version` it shows 3.22.1. Not sure if this is a problem though.

Edit: Below is the code generated from CMakeCache.txt

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: /root/MyProject/build
# It was generated by CMake: /usr/bin/cmake
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Value Computed by CMake
MyProject_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=/root/MyProject/build

//Value Computed by CMake
MyProject_IS_TOP_LEVEL:STATIC=ON

//Value Computed by CMake
MyProject_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=/root/MyProject

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=MyProject

CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:STRING=10.0

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:STRING=root/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=/root/MyProject/build
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=22
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/usr/bin/cmake
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/usr/bin/cpack
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=/usr/bin/ctest
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Unix Makefiles
//Generator instance identifier.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=/root/MyProject
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=1
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=/usr/share/cmake-3.22
//uname command
CMAKE_UNAME:INTERNAL=/usr/bin/uname
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the toolchains file being referenced by *vcpkg* are:

- `-DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/root/vcpkg/scripts/toolchains/linux.cmake`
- `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/root/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`

Try opening the files (`linux.cmake` and `vcpkg.cmake`) and check if they have any hard coded compiler definitions (`CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variables). If there are, edit them to your desired compiler, and if there aren't, add compiler definitions to one of the toolchain files as follow:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/path/to/your/c/compiler/executable")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/your/cpp/compiler/executable")
```

Comment: Tried to add `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")` to `linux.cmake` and `vcpkg.cmake`, nothing happened and the same error persists. I dont understand this at all.

Comment: @LordYggdrasill check your cmake cache file and see which compiler has been found.

Comment: I've edited the main post to show the code generated on cmake cache, I aint sure how to make sense of this.

Comment: I don't see which compiler it found, are you sure the compiler is installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

If `detect_compiler` fails in vcpkg on platforms which are not windows it typically means that whatever build environment you have setup does not work. So If you take a simple `CMakeLists.txt` like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) # desperately chosen to use a low version 
project(Test LANGUAGES C CXX)
```

you will not able to configure it since CMake is not able to go past the compiler checks for C/CXX. You should be able to tell from the [configure log](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-configure-log.7.html) what is going wrong.